# Page as parent for CPT and other pages

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Can't find the solution to set a page to be a parent for both: CPT and pages.
This is my registered post type:

```
register_post_type( 'event', array(
'labels' => $labels,
'has_archive' => true,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','page-attributes', 'excerpt', 'revisions'),
'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ), 
'hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'pollock', 'with_front' => false ),
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'capability_type' => 'post',
//'map_meta_cap'    => true,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
)
```

Pollock page has child pages, but when I add it as a slug to CPT, the pages chierarchy for child pages doesnt work.
Is there a way to make a page for both? or this is how WP premalink structure works?

Comment: That's how permalinks work - you can't have two different content types with the same slug. One will always override the other. What's your use case? You should be able to edit your CPT archive template to display both page content and the actual CPT archive.

Comment: Rewrite rules are patterns that describe what URLs look like for each content type. Given the URL `pollock/something/`, WordPress has to know what `something` is before it goes to look for it in the database, only one rule will "win" in every case.